# I'm encountering a series of errors in my sitecore logs and I've tried disabling several configs but none of them worked

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

ERROR Exception while handling event Sitecore.ContentSearch.Events.IndexingFinishedEvent
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'indexing:end:remote' event

I'm encountering this error in the logs and I have tried disabling some configs and none of them work. So where should I look next to try and resolve this issue? I'm relatively new to sitecore but I haven't found anything with remotely the same error as me online.

Comment: Have you checked your config for what is registered to the  Sitecore.ContentSearch.Events.IndexingFinishedEvent?

Comment: is mongodb setup correctly and running?

Comment: What version of Sitecore you are using (add to the question)

Comment: I'm using Sitecore 8.2
I'll check the mongoDB to see if it is set-up correctly.

Comment: My Sitecore.ContentSearch.Event.IndexingFinishedEvent is from my fresh instance so there's nothing wrong with it.

My moggoDB is set-up correctly so I don't that's the problem.